# Sequence in a oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I need to use the GenerationType.sequence strategy for a table
I write the follow annotation in the class:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_PERFIL", sequenceName="SEQ_PERFIL",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_PERFIL")
@Column(name="PER_CODPERFIL", nullable = false)
private long perCodperfil;
```

To insert I use this code:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(entity);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.refresh(entity);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

When I insert the sequence is incremented (I show that in the database), but the insertion fail, because the primary key is null

```
It said :
Error Code: 1400
Call: INSERT INTO PERFIL (PER_CODPERFIL) VALUES (?) bind => [1 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(24)
```

and it said that PER_CODPERFIL is null
I use Eclipse-link and a Oracle DB

The sentence loggued by eclipse link is :

```
15:05:36,651 INFO    [EclipseLog] SELECT SEQ_SIAC_PERFIL.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL   
15:05:36,761 INFO    [EclipseLog] INSERT INTO PERFIL (PER_CODPERFIL) VALUES (?) bind => [null]
15:05:36,773 INFO    [EclipseLog] SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Try setting the persistence properties eclipselink.logging.parameters to true and the eclipselink.logging.level to FINE or FINEST to see what is being executed.  Also print off the error, as I believe code 1400 refers to inserting null into a not-null field - how have you created the table?  There is only 1 field value being inserted, so be sure there aren't other columns with a not-null constraint.

Comment: thanks! you are right, I have other column with not-null constraint